# modify floating ip description attribute will remove the existing QoS policy

Tags: openstack-neutron

This is openstack Zed version, it turns out qos_policy_id will be reset if the change is on other attributes for floating IP.
Is this a bug?

```
openstack floating ip show 75c41f3f-ea12-4555-947e-7a4803147c0a |grep qos
| qos_policy_id       | 60e612d2-fa01-421a-a4cd-96043c3c7587                                                                                                                                 |

curl -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" http://10.0.52.1:9696/v2.0/floatingips/75c41f3f-ea12-4555-947e-7a4803147c0a -d '{"floatingip": {"description": "testing"}}' 
{"floatingip": {"id": "75c41f3f-ea12-4555-947e-7a4803147c0a", "tenant_id": "c13998dac04045a5acb4464bf2274272", "floating_ip_address": "10.0.56.130", "floating_network_id": "46f94d26-b0b0-49f4-b1e6-d67b5189c018", "router_id": "037c542b-82a1-449a-ac3f-8c29b1f49344", "port_id": "a805c597-0ac7-48fa-bde9-f727beeb5b0e", "fixed_ip_address": "192.168.50.14", "status": "ACTIVE", "description": "testing", "qos_policy_id": null, "port_details": {"name": "test", "network_id": "c2ebde5e-8766-4d4e-9517-f95fd6fd3ec7", "mac_address": "fa:16:3e:7c:fd:c4", "admin_state_up": true, "status": "DOWN", "device_id": "", "device_owner": ""}, "port_forwardings": [], "tags": ["flow_model"], "created_at": "2023-07-04T10:21:20Z", "updated_at": "2023-07-07T06:01:29Z", "revision_number": 262, "project_id": "c13998dac04045a5acb4464bf2274272"}}

openstack floating ip show 75c41f3f-ea12-4555-947e-7a4803147c0a |grep qos
| qos_policy_id       | None
```

Change attributes of floating ip will not affect qos policy

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this issue if you check the QoS policy of your FIP:
$ QOS_ID=$(openstack floating ip show  -f value -c qos_policy_id)

And use this uuid with openstackclient:
$ openstack floating ip set  --description whatever --qos-policy $QOS_ID

Or use the above id in your curl:
curl .... -d '{"floatingip": {"description": "testing", "qos_policy_id": "the Id above"}}'

https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/neutron/+/899469 is the proposed fix, and as I see it can be backported.